# Spring defines beans which the class files are in another jar

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

My project(Maven project) includes three modules:sr-web,sr-domain and sr-dao, just like this:

sr----
     |
     ----sr-domain
     |
     ----sr-dao
     |
     ----sr-web

In the domain module, I have my entities defined, and in the dao module, I define related DAO interface which extends `org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository`
and

```
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor
```

but when I define the Dao beans in applicationContext.xml in the sr-web module, I got the exception:

```
UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setUserDao' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'edu.whu.irlab.scholarreader.dao.repository.UserDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:671)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
... 77 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'edu.whu.irlab.scholarreader.dao.repository.UserDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1466)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1097)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
```

In the sr-web module, my applicationContext.xml is like this:

```
<bean id="authorDao" class="edu.whu.irlab.scholarreader.dao.repository.AuthorDao" abstract="true"/>
    <bean id="journalDao" class="edu.whu.irlab.scholarreader.dao.repository.JournalDao" abstract="true"/>
    <bean id="keywordDao" class="edu.whu.irlab.scholarreader.dao.repository.KeywordDao" abstract="true"/>
    <bean id="paperDao" class="edu.whu.irlab.scholarreader.dao.repository.PaperDao" abstract="true"/>
    <bean id="referenceDao" class="edu.whu.irlab.scholarreader.dao.repository.ReferenceDao" abstract="true"/>
    <bean id="taskDao" class="edu.whu.irlab.scholarreader.dao.repository.TaskDao" abstract="true"/>
    <bean id="userDao" class="edu.whu.irlab.scholarreader.dao.repository.UserDao" abstract="true"/>
```

then how can I define my Dao beans in the sr-web module?

Comment: I guess it has something to do with component scanning. It is not scanning the package where UserDao resides I suppose. Try enabling component scanning on that package as well.

Comment: Your xml is pretty much doing nothing, marking a bean abstract makes it create not an instance. Looks also you use Spring Data JPA so not sure why you are even defining those in XML. I suspect your actual application isn't scanning the proper packages.